# Steam inventory not showing up the whole inventory in PHP

Tags: php, steam-web-api

I have some big problems with using the steam to get the full inventory of a user and get a quantity per item. It only shows up some of the items not actually the full inventory, and i cant find any way to count quantity per item either. I get some items from the inventory and gets the picture of the item.

I already tried with different games.

´´

```
$inventoryJsonUrl = 'https://steamcommunity.com/inventory/76561198077278446/489940/2l=english&count=5000';
$inventoryJsonGet = file_get_contents($inventoryJsonUrl);

$inventories = json_decode($inventoryJsonGet , TRUE);

foreach ($inventories['descriptions'] as $key => $description) {
 $description['appid'];
 $description['market_name'];
 $lol = $description['classid'];
echo '

        <div class="item">
      <img src="https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/class/489940/' . $lol . '/100fx60f" /> <br />
      ' . $description['market_name'] . '
    </div> 
';
}
```

``